# WordPress not registering Theme Customization Section

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-customizer

I am developing my first WordPress Theme and I would like to add a Customization Menu, initially to change Social Networks Link addresses... I have added following to my `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Add Theme Customize Options
 */
function www_perlur_cloud_customize_register($wp_customize) {
  /**
   * Add Social Networks Links section to WordPress Theme Customize Menu
   */
  $wp_customize->add_section( 'www_perlur_cloud_social_networks_links',
    array(
      'title'         => __('Social Networks Links','www_perlur_cloud'),
      'priority'      => 30,
      'capability'    => 'edit_theme_options',
      'description'   => __('Allows you to customize Social Networks Links for PERLUR Group theme.','www_perlur_cloud')
    )
  );
}

/**
 * Activate defined functions.
 *
 */
add_action('init', 'disable_emojis');
add_action('customize_register', 'www_perlur_cloud_customize_register');
```

But when I click Customize in the Theme section of WordPress Administration I do not see the section "Social Network Links". Any idea how it may be, and what I have to do to fix it?

Update 1:

I have added following code into `www_perlur_cloud_customize_register` function:

```
  $wp_customize->add_control('social_icons_color',
    array(
      'type' => 'color',
      'priority' => 10, // Within the section.
      'section' => 'www_perlur_cloud_social_networks', // Required, core or custom.
      'label' => __('Date'),
      'description' => __('This is a date control with a red border.'),
      'input_attrs' => array(
        'class' => 'my-custom-class-for-js',
        'style' => 'border: 1px solid #900',
        'placeholder' => __('mm/dd/yyyy'),
      ),
    'active_callback' => 'is_front_page',
    )
  );
```

and no change... I have even tried to use "Additional CSS" where I added simply /** */ and clicked Publish. But no change... :-(

Update 2:

Could the problem be that the theme directory is `www.perlur.cloud` and not `www_perlur_cloud`?

Comment: Have you tried adding setting to your section?

Answer (score 3):

You won't see the section as there is no control that belongs to that section. In other words, that's a blank section. And customizer doesn't show any blank section, you need at least one control under that section. It's a usual behavior, so no worries.